# How to change the font size consistently on ActiveX command buttons

Tags: excel, vba

So i have an excel workbook with ~15 ActiveX Command Buttons that are selected to run macros. They are all the same height and width but i have a sub running continously to always set the height and width to consistent values. This was implemented as sometimes the buttons would start changing sizes when pressed.

Recently we have noticed that sometimes the font size will keep reducing in size also so i wanted to hardwire their font size into the macros.

I have tried using functions like `CommandButton1.font.size = 15`. This has worked but when I apply it to each of the buttons that same font size ends up displaying vastly different per button? I thought it might be due to the buttons dimensions but this cant be the case since this is the same across the buttons. Is there some sort of auto size function that will keep it consistent?

Comment: The visible size of a text also depends on the Font.Type property. Are they the same?

Comment: @Blackcat Is Font.Type correct? I have try to view it ```Test = CommandButton1.Object.Font.Type
    MsgBox (Test)``` but i get an error to say this does not exist

Comment: Sorry. Font.Name gives the type of the font

Comment: Try this snippet. Sub fonttype()

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Count
With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(i).Object
Debug.Print .Font.Name, .Font.Size
End With
Next i
End Sub

Comment: Yeah they are all Calibri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub fonttype()
For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Count
    With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(i).Object
         On Error Resume Next
         .Font.Size = 15
    End With
Next i
On Error Goto 0
End Sub
```

After this all objects will have the same font size.

With the On Error statement eliminate objects which hasn't property .Font.Size